# How to find real number with regex C++

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have a string with some real number.

> char buf1[256] = ">m Current Irradiance [mW/cm2] = 9.1 \r\n"; // Range
>   0.0 ~ 999.9

Range of Real number are between 0.0 and 999.9. There is no negative value.

I wrote sample code such as below. I used regex expression for this.

> "\s\d*.\d\s"

Anyway, I got correct result at this moment. However, I also look forward to more good expression from below site.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

I've tried many thing for this. for example,

> [-+]?([0-9]*.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)

I failed to find real number. I just want to know whether my original expression is best one or not.

Code Snippet :

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost\algorithm\string.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::algorithm;

TEST_CASE("string parsing", "[STRING]"){

    typedef std::vector<string>::iterator intStr;
    typedef std::vector<double>::iterator dubIter;

    char buf1[256] = ">m Current Irradiance [mW/cm2] = 9.1 \r\n"; // Range 0.0 ~ 999.9
    char buf2[256] = ">m Current Irradiance [mW/cm2] = 90.1 \r\n"; // Range 0.0 ~ 999.9
    char buf3[256] = ">m Current Irradiance [mW/cm2] = 990.1 \r\n"; // Range 0.0 ~ 999.9

    std::vector<string> strVec;
    strVec.push_back(buf1);
    strVec.push_back(buf2);
    strVec.push_back(buf3);

    std::vector<double> dubVec;
    dubVec.push_back(9.1);
    dubVec.push_back(90.1);
    dubVec.push_back(990.1);

    try{
        for (std::pair<intStr, dubIter> i(strVec.begin(), dubVec.begin()); i.first != strVec.end(); ++i.first, ++i.second)
        {
            boost::iterator_range<std::string::iterator> r = find_regex((*i.first), boost::regex{ "\\s\\d*.\\d\\s" });
            std::string ret(r.begin(), r.end());

            {
                CHECK((*i.second) == std::stod(ret));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (const std::invalid_argument& ia){
        std::cerr << "Invalid argument: " << ia.what() << '\n';
    }
}

//$ testAny.exe
//== == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == == =
//All tests passed(3 assertions in 1 test case)
```

Comment: The best regex is the one that fits your needs.

Comment: First thing you must define your grammar, i.e. give a rigorous and detailed definition of the strings that you consider a valid real number. Without this information, we cannot help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that you saw in the website:

```
"[+-]?(\\d*\\.\\d+\|\\d+)"
```

will also match single number, which might or might not be what you want. In your examples, they will match the 2 in the cm2. If you really want to match only number with decimal points in them then just remove the or case:

```
"[+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the "." in your regexp.

```
"\s\d*.\d\s"
```

should at least be:

```
"\s\d*\.\d\s"
```

Otherwise the "." will match ANY character.